# automatic change post date when post is 30 days old

Tags: plugin-development

I am using below code, but not working. pls tell me is there any other way or where i am doing mistake?

```
//cron work
function isa_add_every_minutes( $schedules ) {

    $schedules['every_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 60,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 1 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );

    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_minutes' );

// Add function to register event to WordPress init
add_action( 'init', 'register_event');

// Function which will register the event
function register_event() {

    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'post_status_change' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_minutes', 'post_status_change' );
    }
}

add_action( 'post_status_change', 'post_status_change_all' );

// This function will run once the 'delete_post_revisions' is called
function post_status_change_all() {

 global $wpdb;
  $daystogo = "5";
  $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > '$daystogo')";
  echo $sql;
  $wpdb->query( $sql );
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now. I have been added : `'date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); '`
there was the time error. current time, i was getting wrong.